# How do I had vertical grid lines to an ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to add vertical grid lines to an ag-Grid for angular 2 (making it a bit more excel-like).

Do I need to make a custom theme (not use ag-theme-balham)?

Does anyone have an example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution could be to style the cells by adding for example:

```
cellStyle: {border: '1px solid'}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Use this **Stackblitz** for your reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-bss-test-s5pxxc?file=app/app.component.ts

You can try to put different size for the border for better look & feel:

```
border: 'solid',
borderTopWidth: '0.5px',
borderRightWidth: '0.5px',
borderLeftWidth: '0.5px',
borderBottomWidth: '0.5px'
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Override the ag-grid value:

```
   .ag-cell
   {
      border-right-color: black;
      border-right-width: 1px ;
      border-right-style: solid ;
    }
```

for cells 
and for the header

```
 .ag-header-cell,  .ag-header-group-cell {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In column definition we can able to define vertical alignment **cellStyle: {'border-right': '1px dotted'}**

```
const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
        return {
            cellStyle: {'padding-left': 0 ,'border-right': '1px dotted'},
            sortable: true,
            editable: false,
            flex: 1,
            filter: true,
            resizable: true,
            floatingFilter: true,
            suppressMenu: true,
            floatingFilterComponentParams: { suppressFilterButton: true },
        };
    }, []);
```